# How to add click event in angular 2 when rendering text in [innerHTML]

Tags: angular

Hello I want to bind some raw data to view in angular4. I'am binding them to view like so:

in controller:

```
let news = {
 content:'lorem ipsum #link-90 some other content',
}
```

in template:

```
<span [innerHTML]="news.content"></span>
```

It will render
lorem ipsum #link-90 some other content
In some part of string i i want to replace #link-90 with a href.
I  replace sring and generate link `<a (click)="functionName(90)">link</a>` 
But after I bind it to my template i have no click event. Is there any way to do it?

so final result working like i wrote in template:

```
<span>lorem ipsum <a (click)="functionName(90)">link</a> some other content</span>
```

Comment: add more details to the question, it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: in case some one looking for this i just addEventListner after render it in DOM